# Dependencies for using Spring Cache

Tags: java, spring, caching, dependencies, spring-3

I want to use [Spring Cache features](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) but I don't know what dependedencies this module has. I have a configuration like:

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    ...

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<cache:annotation-driven />
```

But `<cache:annotation-driven />` is not being recognized. It gives this error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'cache:annotation-driven'
```

I think it comes because I don't the jar file of a Spring module because I haven't added all (I add them when I really need them).

What spring modules jars are required to get Spring Cache working? or at elast where can I find this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need:

```
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
```

And the correct xsd is:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd
```

Comment: I already had added it, though I hadn't include it in my question. There must be something more missing (I think it may be a jar file)

Comment: Thanks that error stopped. The documentation in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html  says the xsd I had so I suppose it is wrong. Just another question. Should I change the mvc xsd from spring-mvc-3.0.xsd to spring-mvc-3.1.xsd (because the documentation also says spring-mvc-3.0.xsd)?

Comment: Actually, both XSDs are correct, but this one is can be downloaded, so that IDE can validate against it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand that this feature is a part of Spring 3.1, which is not released yes?

So, you need to use Spring jars from the [milestone build of Spring 3.1.](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/)

Comment: @Javi: Do you get that error when running a program, or in IDE?

Comment: in IDE, I think Bozho answer is right though I haven't check it at all due to another error